# Match Not Working and want to output tags dynamically

Tags: xml, xslt-1.0

I have this source xml from a Cognos system I wish to transform to an output xml using xsl:

```
<dataset  xmlns="http://developer.cognos.com/schemas/xmldata/1/"  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<metadata>
    <item name="REFWO" type="xs:string" length="18"/>
    <item name="STARTDATEENTERED" type="xs:string" length="16002"/>
    <item name="REGULARHRS" type="xs:string" length="102"/>
    <item name="SOMEDESC" type="xs:string" length="16002"/>
    <item name="LABORCODE" type="xs:string" length="26"/>
    <item name="GENAPPRSERVRECEIPT" type="xs:string" length="4"/>
    <item name="GLCREDITACCT" type="xs:string" length="52"/>
    <item name="OUTSIDE" type="xs:string" length="4"/>
    <item name="SITEID" type="xs:string" length="12"/>
    <item name="TOTREC" type="xs:int" precision="1"/>
</metadata>
<data>
    <row>

        <value>12345678</value>
        <value>2020-12-22</value>
        <value>2.00</value>
        <value>MECHANIC</value>
        <value>ABCD01</value>
        <value>0</value>
        <value>11111.11.1111.1111.111.11</value>
        <value>0</value>
        <value>CDEFG</value>
        <value>5</value>
    </row>
    <row>
        <value>12345678</value>
        <value>2020-12-22</value>
        <value>2.00</value>
        <value>MECHANIC</value>
        <value>ABCD02</value>
        <value>1</value>
        <value>11111.11.1111.1111.111.11</value>
        <value>1</value>
        <value>CDEFG</value>
        <value>5</value>
    </row>
</data>
```

Here is the xsl I am trying to get off the ground..
the initial problem is it never executes the match.. is it my namespace?
(The second  problem is I am trying to build the output tag dynamically but I'm not
sure of the approach.)

```
    <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  exclude-result-prefixes="xs">
<xsl:output method="xml" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="xs:dataset"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="xs:dataset">
        <xsl:text>
        </xsl:text>
    <xsl:for-each select="xs:dataset/xs:data/xs:row">
                <xsl:text>
                </xsl:text>
        <!--<xsl:value-of select="max:OBJECTNAME" />
        <xsl:value-of select="max:NAME" />-->
        <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&lt;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="//dataset/metadata/item[1]/@name" />
        <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&gt;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of
                    select="concat(xs:value[1],'.',xs:NAME)"/>
        <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&lt;/</xsl:text>

        <xsl:value-of select="//dataset/metadata/item[1]/@name" />
        <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&gt;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:for-each>

</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I can't tell if my approach for building the tags dynamically is proper. I am stuck with a fairly old version of xls processor.

For example the first line in the metadata is this:

```
<metadata>
    <item name="REFWO" type="xs:string" length="18"/>
```

Indicating that the output tag for each first row  value tag would look like this

```
<LABTRANS><REFWO>12345678</REFWO>
```

If the first metadata row had been this:

```
<metadata>
    <item name="STARTDATEENTERED" type="xs:string" length="16002"/>
```

Then the output tag I need would of looked like this (hence dynamically building the output tag):

```
<LABTRANS><STARTDATEENTERED>12345678</STARTDATEENTERED>
```

Expected Eventual Output as follows... please note that the tags in the output come from data at this location

```
/dataset/metadata/item
```

And the actual data for each tag comes from each supplied input value at this location

```
/dataset/data/row/value
```

Here is the xsl so far:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<PublishTSTLABTRANS xmlns="http://www.ibm.com/maximo" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" creationDateTime="2021-05-20T20:31:26-04:00" transLanguage="EN" baseLanguage="EN" messageID="155701621557087518337" maximoVersion="7 6 20190514-1348 V7611-365" event="0">
  <TSTLABTRANSSet>
    <LABTRANS>
      <GENAPPRSERVRECEIPT>1</GENAPPRSERVRECEIPT>
      <GLCREDITACCT>11111.11.1111.1111.111.11</GLCREDITACCT>
      <LABORCODE>ABCD01</LABORCODE>
      <MEMO>MECHANIC</MEMO>
      <ORGID>OFMC</ORGID>
      <OUTSIDE>0</OUTSIDE>
      <OWNERSYSID />
      <REFWO>12345678</REFWO>
      <REGULARHRS>2</REGULARHRS>
      <SENDERSYSID>CO</SENDERSYSID>
      <SITEID>CDEFG</SITEID>
      <STARTDATEENTERED>2020-12-22T00:00:00-05:00</STARTDATEENTERED>
    </LABTRANS>
    <LABTRANS>
      <GENAPPRSERVRECEIPT>1</GENAPPRSERVRECEIPT>
      <GLCREDITACCT>11111.11.1111.1111.111.11</GLCREDITACCT>
      <LABORCODE>ABCD02</LABORCODE>
      <MEMO>MECHANIC</MEMO>
      <ORGID>OFMC</ORGID>
      <OUTSIDE>1</OUTSIDE>
      <OWNERSYSID />
      <REFWO>12345678</REFWO>
      <REGULARHRS>2</REGULARHRS>
      <SENDERSYSID>CO</SENDERSYSID>
      <SITEID>CDEFG</SITEID>
      <STARTDATEENTERED>2020-12-22T00:00:00-05:00</STARTDATEENTERED>
    </LABTRANS>
  </TSTLABTRANSSet>
</PublishTSTLABTRANS>
```

Any hints/comments/instructions/ptrs are appreciated. Especially my brain dead 'why isn't it matching'

Comment: Please edit your question and add the expected output. -- Hint: you are using the wrong namespace. Also, there should never be a need to produce markup using unescaped text.

Comment: Your dataset element has a namespace that does not have a prefix.  Here's a previous answer that may help you.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43255226/to-select-element-with-multiple-namespaces-on-an-element-with-xslt-1-0-2-0/43260767#43260767

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest you try it along the lines of:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:cgn="http://developer.cognos.com/schemas/xmldata/1/"
xmlns="http://www.ibm.com/maximo" 
exclude-result-prefixes="cgn">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/cgn:dataset">
    <xsl:variable name="field-labels" select="cgn:metadata/cgn:item" />
    <PublishTSTLABTRANS>
        <TSTLABTRANSSet>
            <xsl:for-each select="cgn:data/cgn:row">
                <LABTRANS>
                    <xsl:for-each select="cgn:value">
                        <xsl:variable name="i" select="position()" />
                        <xsl:element name="{$field-labels[$i]/@name}">
                            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                        </xsl:element>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </LABTRANS>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </TSTLABTRANSSet>
    </PublishTSTLABTRANS>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Note:

1. the declaration of the namespace using the `cgn` prefix and the use of this prefix when addressing the elements in the source XML;
2. the declaration of the default namespace to place all elements of the output in that namespace;
3. the use of the `xsl:element` instruction to create elements whose name is determined dynamically at runtime;
4. the use of an [attribute value template](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xslt-19991116/#attribute-value-templates) to calculate the element's name.

I am not sure where the data shown in the attributes of the `PublishTSTLABTRANS` element is supposed to come from.